# How to display correct amount of change?

Tags: java, rounding

I am pretty new to java and am trying to create a simple program that converts an amount of money into change. However, I find that the program always prints one penny less than necessary.

I would have just added 1 to my pennies variable before printing but this would mean that when change is 0, it would still add a penny as change.

Here is my code:

```java
change = amtPaid-Math.round((total*1.13)*100)/100.0;
pennies = (int) (change * 100);
twenties = (int)(pennies/2000);
        pennies %= 2000;
tens = (int)(pennies/1000);
        pennies %= 1000;
fives = (int)(pennies/500);
        pennies %= 500;
toonies = (int)(pennies/200);
        pennies %= 200;
loonies = (int)(pennies/100);
        pennies %= 100;
quarters = (int)(pennies/25);
        pennies %= 25;
dimes = (int)(pennies/10);
        pennies %= 10;
nickels = (int)(pennies/5);
        pennies %= 5;
```

I get this output after providing sample input:

```java
The change will be:  1.83

To make up this amount, you will need:
      0  twenty-dollar bills      0  ten-dollar bills
      0  five-dollar bills        0  toonies
      1  loonies                  3  quarters
      0  dimes                    1  nickels
      2  pennies
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: display pennies the first time it's computed, to check if there is some kind of rounding error !?

Comment: It's something to do with this `amtPaid-Math.round((total*1.13)*100)/100.0;` presumably

Comment: I've removed your [tag:concurrency] as I don't see how this question has anything to do with this subject/multithreading.

Comment: Print the value of `pennies` right after the first time you assign a value to it.  Does it actually print as `183`?

Comment: Don't worry about it....there are no pennies in Canada. There are however Loonies and Toonies.

Comment: @VGR no it doesnt actually. Why could this be happening?

Comment: Most likely, the value is less than 1.83, but the double value is being rounded when you print it.  What code are you using to print "The change will be"?

Comment: @VGR Here it is:
`System.out.println("The change will be:  $" + Math.round(change*100)/100.0);'

Comment: If `change` is 1.828, then `change*100` is 182.8.  Rounding it produces 183.  But `(int) (change * 100)` does not round, it truncates the decimal part entirely, leaving you with 182.  So your program’s coin output is correct.  If you want consistency, use [Math.floor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) instead of Math.round in your print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, get your **Grand Total** (cost and taxes all in) to a decimal precision of no more than **2** (ie: 55.28). **Don't allow the decimal precision to be more than 2**. Whatever the rounding mechanism you use, make sure your happy with the final result.

Subtract the **Amount Owed** from the **Amount Paid** and make sure the final result is to a decimal precision of **2** (ie: 60.00 - 55.2814 = 4.7186 = 4.72 {rounded-up}). By not rounding properly to a decimal precision of 2 is where you can loose or gain a penny when calculating returned change.

Break the **Amount To Return** into **Dollars** and **Cents**. Both should be integer values (ie: 4 Dollars and 72 Cents).

```
// A value for the sake of this example. Taxes Included!
double totalOwed   = 52.26534;   
// Round to a precision of 2 (round UP on .5)
double grandTotal  = BigDecimal.valueOf(totalOwed)
                     .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
// A value for the sake of this example.    
double amountPaid  = 60.00;    
// Round to a precision of 2 (round UP on .5)
double returnValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountPaid - grandTotal)
                     .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

int dollars = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(returnValue).split("\\.")[0]);
int cents   = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(returnValue).split("\\.")[1]);
```

Work out the bill currency to be returnd and add it to a List for display later. There are a LOT of different ways to do this. Here is one way:

```
List<String> change = new ArrayList<>();
int returnVal;

// Some displayable information
change.add("Total Cost:    --> " + String.valueOf(grandTotal));
change.add("Total Paid:    --> " + String.valueOf(amountPaid));
change.add("Return change: --> " + String.valueOf(returnValue));

// 100 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 100) {
    returnVal = dollars / 100;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Hundred Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 100);
}
// 50 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 50) {
    returnVal = dollars / 50;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Fifty Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 50);
}
// 20 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 20) {
    returnVal = dollars / 20;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Twenty Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 20);
}
// 10 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 10) {
    returnVal = dollars / 10;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Ten Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 10);
}
// 5 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 5) {
    returnVal = dollars / 5;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Five Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 5);
}
// 2 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 2) {
    returnVal = dollars / 2;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Two Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 2);
}
// 1 Dollar Bills 
if (dollars >= 1) {
    returnVal = dollars / 1;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " One Dollar Bill(s)");
    dollars -= (returnVal * 1);
}

// Quarters (working against cents now)
if (cents >= 25) {
    returnVal = cents / 25;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Quarter(s)");
    cents -= (returnVal * 25);
}
// Dimes
if (cents >= 10) {
    returnVal = cents / 10;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Dime(s)");
    cents -= (returnVal * 10);
}
// Nickles
if (cents >= 5) {
    returnVal = cents / 5;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Nickle(s)");
    cents -= (returnVal * 5);
}
// Pennies
if (cents >= 1) {
    returnVal = cents / 1;
    change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + " Pennies");
    cents -= (returnVal * 1);
}

// Display the Change-Back in Console Window
for (String str : change) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

As you can see there is a lot of repetitious code in the example above. You can get rid of this by doing it yet another way. You can utilize an Array or Collection mechanism to hold the Dollar and coin denominations, for example:

```
// A value for the sake of this example. Taxes Included!
double totalOwed   = 52.26534;   
// Round to a precision of 2 (round UP on .5)
double grandTotal  = BigDecimal.valueOf(totalOwed)
                     .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();
// A value for the sake of this example.    
double amountPaid  = 60.00;    
// Round to a precision of 2 (round UP on .5)
double returnValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(amountPaid - grandTotal)
                     .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP).doubleValue();

int dollars = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(returnValue).split("\\.")[0]);
int cents   = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(returnValue).split("\\.")[1]);

List<String> change = new ArrayList<>();
int returnVal;

// Using arrays (or a collection mechanism) like this 
// allows you to set whatever denominations you like.
String[][] dollarDenominations = {
    {"100", " Hundred Dollar Bill(s)"},
    {"50" , " Fifty Dollar Bill(s)"  },
    {"20" , " Twenty Dollar Bill(s)" },
    {"10" , " Ten Dollar Bill(s)"    },
    {"5"  , " Five Dollar Bill(s)"   },
    {"2"  , " Two Dollar Bill(s)"    },
    {"1"  , " One Dollar Bill(s)"    }
};

// Although not commonly used, you might even want to
// add 50 cent pieces to the Array.
String[][] coinDenominations = {
    {"25", " Quarter(s)"},
    {"10", " Dime(s)"   },
    {"5" , " Nickle(s)" },
    {"1" , " Pennies"   }
};

// Some displayable information
change.add("Total Cost:    --> " + String.valueOf(grandTotal));
change.add("Total Paid:    --> " + String.valueOf(amountPaid));
change.add("Return change: --> " + String.valueOf(returnValue));

// Dollar Denominations
for (int i = 0; i < dollarDenominations.length; i++) {
    int denom = Integer.parseInt(dollarDenominations[i][0]);
    String typeString = dollarDenominations[i][1];
    if (dollars >= denom) {
        returnVal = dollars / denom;
        change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + typeString);
        dollars -= (returnVal * denom);
    }
}

// Coin Denominations
for (int i = 0; i < coinDenominations.length; i++) {
    int denom = Integer.parseInt(coinDenominations[i][0]);
    String typeString = coinDenominations[i][1];
    if (cents >= denom) {
        returnVal = cents / denom;
        change.add("  " + String.valueOf(returnVal) + typeString);
        cents -= (returnVal * denom);
    }
}

// Display the Change-Back data in Console Window...
for (String str : change) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

As said before, there are several other ways to do this sort of thing. The important thing is to work against Change-Back values that are to 2 decimal places. After all...to my knowledge, there is no such denomination as a one-sixth penny (there is no denomination for [**mills**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mill_(currency))). The US at one time (between 1793 and 1857) use to have a **half-Penny** but that no longer exists and never ever will again for obvious reasons. In Canada there is no Penny since it costs almost 2 cents to make one and ultimately (in my opinion) the United States will most likely follow this scheme and save millions upon millions in the process since it also costs approx. 1.82+ cents to make a US penny.